# JavaScript - How to Create a List of Numbers Between 1 and Whatever The User Enters (Num), Then Multiply Those Numbers Together?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, iteration

I'm trying to solve this problem:

https://www.coderbyte.com/editor/guest:First%20Factorial:JavaScript

My idea is to create a variable `list` that generates all digits between 1 and whatever the user enters as `num`.

How would I say `let list = //integers between 1 and (num)`

And then multiply all numbers in list together?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. How about you try doing that, and if you have problems with it, ask a specific question. Getting the answer given to you fully formed is unlikely to help you learn. Search around Stack Overflow too; we've got a **lot** of questions on here; likely, we have one about getting an array of numbers between 1 and a given number.

Comment: I'm not asking for the answer to be given to me fully formed. First I'm trying to learn how to say "create a variable (list) that lists all integers between 1 and whatever number is entered (num)". How do I do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>multiply</title>

</head>

<body>
    Enter number : <input id="inputnum" />
    <input type ="button" value="Submit" onclick="multiply();" />
    <div id="outputnew"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(JavaScript goes in the `<head></head>` section):

```
<script>
function multiply() {
    let num = document.getElementById("inputnum").value;
    let sum = 1;

    for (let i=1; i<= num; i++) {
        sum = sum * i;
    }

    document.getElementById("outputnew").innerHTML  = "All of the values between 
    1 and " +num+ " multiplied together equals:" + sum ;

}
</script>
```

This creates a function `multiply()` where I defined two variables: `num` and `sum`.

`num` gets the value of whatever the user enters for the `<input>` field with the id `"inputnum"` and `sum` starts out as 1.

We then create a `for-loop` where we get all of the integers from 1 to `(num)` and multiply then them together with `sum = sum * i;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
const x = readline();

const array = Array.from({length: x}).map((_, i) => i + 1);
/* Now you have [1, 2, 3, ... , n] */

const result = array.reduce((previousItem, currentItem) => previousItem * currentItem);
/* Now you have 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n */
```

Comment: Ok so `readline();` gets the value of `(num)`, then, I'm assuming?

Comment: @HappyHands31 Common stdin produces `string` value for user input, but `readline()`method of the website(`coderbyte.com`) produces user input as it is. If you write asdf in input field and run `const x = readline()`, you can see `ReferenceError: asdf is not defined` error.